# Insert value depending on the value of another column trigger sql

Tags: sql, laravel-5, triggers

So here's my problem. I have excel file upload. what i need is I need to insert '1' or '2' in one column while populating data from excel file to sql db depend on the value of another column. is it possible to create trigger that inserts while uploading data in the same table?. Thank you.

```
 CREATE
/*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
TRIGGER `trg_utCode` BEFORE  INSERT ON `exceldisbursements` 
FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN 
 UPDATE exceldisbursements
 SET ut_id = CASE
 WHEN ex_responsibility_center LIKE '001-05%' THEN 2
 WHEN ex_responsibility_center LIKE '001-5%' THEN 2
 ELSE 1
END;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

what you're making there is a full update on your table (you don't have any where clause). You just need to use the ":new" bind variable. eg:

```
BEGIN 
 :new.ut_id = CASE
 WHEN :new.ex_responsibility_center LIKE '001-05%' THEN 2
 WHEN :new.ex_responsibility_center LIKE '001-5%' THEN 2
 ELSE 1
 END;
END;
```